# Opensearch/Elasticsearch sorting with two parameters of equal weight/priority

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

I'm trying to understand how to solve this in Opensearch (but Elasticsearch solutions will do).

Essentially, I have an index of jobs and I'm trying to sort them according to two parameters, giving equal weight to each: subscription tier and a popularity score (each being fields in each job doc).

Normally, when you sort you sort based on one first and then the other, essentially I need to blend them and give 50/50 weight to each.

When jobs are sorted by relevance (default), we want this to be a combination of both their subscription tier and the jobs individual relevance score, according to a weighting w, e.g. this formula:

Jobs would be ranked according to their weighted score.

Weighted score = (r1 x w) + (r2 x (1-w)
where:

r1 = the position a job ranks for a given search if only relevance is considered; and
r2 = the position a job ranks for a given search if only subscription is considered

However the problem of is I would need to perform multiple searches to obtain the rank for each sorting criteria of each job, which would be terribly inefficient. I'm trying to see if I can solve this problem natively with Opensearch.

I was trying to compute this as a script score function for example, using purely the two fields, but they are totally unrelated and not normalised between then, so assigning equal weight becomes challenging.

Here is what I tried so far. First adding some test documents:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"1"}}
{"title":"Job 1","popularity_score":"0.105","bid":"100"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"2"}}
{"title":"Job 2","popularity_score":"0.06","bid":"50"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"3"}}
{"title":"Job 3","popularity_score":"0.099","bid":"25"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"4"}}
{"title":"Job 4","popularity_score":"0.155","bid":"5"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"5"}}
{"title":"Job 5","popularity_score":"0.028","bid":"100"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"6"}}
{"title":"Job 6","popularity_score":"0.118","bid":"100"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"7"}}
{"title":"Job 7","popularity_score":"0.186","bid":"50"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"8"}}
{"title":"Job 8","popularity_score":"0.019","bid":"25"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"9"}}
{"title":"Job 9","popularity_score":"0.081","bid":"5"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"10"}}
{"title":"Job 10","popularity_score":"0.124","bid":"100"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"11"}}
{"title":"Job 11","popularity_score":"0.163","bid":"100"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"12"}}
{"title":"Job 12","popularity_score":"0.025","bid":"50"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"13"}}
{"title":"Job 13","popularity_score":"0.16","bid":"25"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"14"}}
{"title":"Job 14","popularity_score":"0.119","bid":"5"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"15"}}
{"title":"Job 15","popularity_score":"0.16","bid":"100"}
```

Then, I tried to use the script score so that each factor contributes half to the sorting:

```
GET tier-sort/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc['popularity_score'].value"
          },
        },
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc['bid'].value"
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem however is normalisation. Bid and Popularity are completely different scales. How can this be achieved in Elasticsearch? Is there a way to do this natively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to change the ranking of search results of Elasticsearch/Opensearch

1. Add **boosting logic** (eg. [script_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-script-score-query.html), [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), [rank features](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/rank-features.html)) to change the final `_score`
2. [Sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/sort-search-results.html) on certain field(s) or specify **sort logic**. By default, ES will sort on `_score`, but **if you specify sort logic other than `_score`, the boosting logic will be ignored**, and `_score` will be set as null, only sort part take effective

If you have both factors in different scale, then the rank_features can help you to normalize efficiently, eg.

Adding some docs

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"1"}}
{"title":"Job 1","rank":{"popularity_score":0.105,"bid":100}}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"2"}}
{"title":"Job 2","rank":{"popularity_score":0.06,"bid":50}}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"3"}}
{"title":"Job 3","rank":{"popularity_score":0.099,"bid":25}}
```

Apply **rank_feature** in query

```
GET tier-sort/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "should": [
         {
           "rank_feature": {
             "field": "rank.popularity_score",
             "saturation": {},
             "boost": 0.5
           }
         },
         {
           "rank_feature": {
             "field": "rank.bid",
             "saturation": {},
             "boost": 0.5
           }
         }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can choose different [built-in functions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html#rank-feature-query-functions) in rank feature and adjust the **pivot** to control the result. You can also use [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/search-explain.html) to get know how the score been calculated in detail. This can help you to check whether the query run as you expectation

Comment: I updated my post with a few more details. Essentially the issue I have is both factors are different scales so I end up with the issue on how to normalise them efficiently.

Comment: I think another native feature in ES you can try with is [rank_features](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/rank-features.html). It have some [built-in function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html#rank-feature-query-functions) which will give u normalized score. From query performance wise, this should also help compare with function score or script score

Comment: Hi,
Ranked features is exactly what I needed!
If you want to edit your answer I'll make that the solution.
thanks!

Comment: I update the answer. Let me know if anything still unclear. Thanks!